# Delay 6 seconds before beginning a function that will loop itself, small, not working, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

I'm trying to create a 6 second delay before the `heartColor(e)` function begins, the function will then continue to loop. I don't understand why it's starting the function immediatley, and not waiting the 6 seconds it's supposed to, what did I do wrong?

```
function heartColor(e) {
    e.animate({
        color: '#7ea0dd'
    }, 1000).animate({
        color: '#986db9'
    }, 1000).animate({
        color: '#9fc54e'
    }, 1000, function(){
        heartColor(e)
    })
}

$('.something').hover(function(){
    setTimeout(heartColor($(this)), 6000);
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `setTimeout()` function expects its first parameter to be a function *reference* (or a string, but that's not recommended for several reasons). You are not passing it a function reference, you are calling the `heartColor()` function and passing the result to `setTimeout()`. So the function executes immediately, and then after six seconds nothing happens because the return value was undefined so `setTimeout()` had nothing to work with.

Try this instead:

```
$('.something').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      heartColor($this);
    }, 6000);
})
```

The reason I have included an anonymous function as the parameter to `setTimeout` is that your call to `heartColor()` needs to pass a parameter through. If it didn't have any parameters you could do this:

```
setTimeout(heartColor, 6000);
```

Note there are no parentheses after `heartColor` - that gets a reference to the function *without* calling it so that later `setTimeout` calls it for you. But you can't get a reference to the function and provide parameters at the same time so you need to wrap the call up in another function. You could do this:

```
var $this = $(this);
function callHeartColor() {
   heartColor($this);
}
setTimeout(callHeartColor, 6000);
```

My original answer with the anonymous function is kind of short hand for that and (most people find it) more convenient.

The reason I have created a variable `$this` is because of the way the `this` keyword works in JavaScript, which depends on how a function is called. If you simply said `heartColor($(this))` inside the anonymous function (or the `callHeartColor()` function) `this` would not be the element being hovered over.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not `setTimeout(heartColor, 6000, $(this));`?

Comment: @WesleyJohnson - Because, convenient though that would be, it doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

you are invoking the function heartColor instead of passing it as a parameter. you have to do:

```
$('.something').hover(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){heartColor($(this))}, 6000);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
$('.something').hover(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {heartColor($(this));}, 6000);
})
```